# Help with characteristic method technicality

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'd like to derive a slightly more general result than the transport equation.

I have the PDE $0 = u_y(x,y) - g(y)f(x)u_x(x,y)$ with $u(x,0) = h(x),$

and in imploring the characteristic method, I arrive at

$$ 1 = \frac{dy}{ds}, \ g(y)f(x) = \frac{dx}{ds}, \ 0 = z(x(s),y(s)) .$$

Now, when I'm integrating these ODE, where I'm confused is whether I treat the $g(y)$ term as a constant or if I can integrate $\int_{s_0}^{s} g(v)dv = \int_{s_0}^{x(s)}\frac{dx/ds}{f(x)}ds.$

I'm sure this solution has some kind of ascertainable result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$u_y(x,y) - g(y)f(x)u_x(x,y)=0$$
Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs :
$$\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{dx}{- g(y)f(x)}=\frac{du}{0}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from $\frac{du}{0}\quad\implies\quad du=0\quad $ thus :
$$u=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{dx}{- g(y)f(x)}\quad\implies\quad g(y)dy+\frac{dx}{f(x)}=0$
$$\int g(y)dy+\int\frac{dx}{f(x)}=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE  on the form of implicit equation $c_1=\Phi(c_2)$ is :
$$\boxed{u(x,y)=\Phi\left(\int_{y_0}^y g(\mu)d\mu+\int_{x_0}^x\frac{d\nu}{f(\nu)}\right)}$$
$\Phi$ is an arbitrary function (to be determined according to the specified condition).

Condition : $u(x,0)=h(x)$

We set $y_0=0$ into the above general solution without loss of generality.
$$h(x)=\Phi\left(\int_{0}^0 g(\mu)d\mu+\int_{x_0}^x\frac{d\nu}{f(\nu)}\right)$$
$$h(x)=\Phi\left(\int_{x_0}^x\frac{d\nu}{f(\nu)}\right)$$
Let $X(x)=\int_{x_0}^x\frac{d\nu}{f(\nu)}$

Supposing that $\frac{d\nu}{f(\nu)}$ is integrable and that the inverse function of $X(x)$ can be expressed on the form of $x=\Psi(X)$, then :
$$\Phi(X)=h\bigg(\Psi(X)\bigg)$$

Now $\Phi(X)$ is a known function since $\Psi(X)$ has been expressed. We put $\Phi(X)$ into the above general solution where $X=\int_{0}^y g(\mu)d\mu+\int_{x_0}^x\frac{d\nu}{f(\nu)}$
$$\boxed{u(x,y)=h\left(\Psi\left(\int_{0}^y g(\mu)d\mu+\int_{x_0}^x\frac{d\nu}{f(\nu)}\right)\right)}$$
This is the particular solution which satisfies both the PDE and the condition.

Note that obtaining the function $\Psi$  from the function $1/f(x)$ involves an integration and then an inversion which is the most difficult part of the task. The most often this is problematic. Certainly few functions $f(x)$ are nice enough to finally get an analytical result.

Comment:

One might be surprised that an arbitrary constant $x_0$ seems to remains in the final equation. As a matter of fact the final result doesn't depends on the choice of starting point $x_0$ for the integration. Try with some examples of explicit functions $f(x)$. You will obseved that $x_0$ vanishes along the process of inversion.

Comment: "Kettle of fish"?! :-D

Comment: Thank you very much JJacquelin, I'll look this over. What is puzzling to me is why there is this extra function $\Psi$. WolframAlpha says the result is $h(\int(g) + \int(1/f)),$ but I had reason to believe that was incorrect and so asked here. Now you've illustrated that indeed there is a missing component that Wolfram didn't specify. Although I've seen the $dx = dy = dz$ formula implored in the characteristic method before, I don't understand why it's applicable here. I think you mean $du/ds=0$ and thus integrating yields a constant? How do you formalize dividing by 0 like this?

Comment: Hi Jacquelin, I also notice you have an external account where you publish literature. Do you happen to have a tutorial on the characteristic method?

Comment: Also, would you be willing to clarify directly what $\Psi$ is? It seems like you're suggesting $\Psi$ is the inverse of $\int 1/f$ which makes sense to me, I found something similar when I tried to go about this and I don't mind taking the inverse.

Comment: And, how do you know $c_1 = \Phi(c_2)$? What is the basis for assuming that?

Comment: They are a lot of questions. 

First : One can see directly from the PDE that $u(x,y)=$constant is a particular solution. This is also a characteristic equation $u=c_1$. 

Second : $dx=dy=dz$ is not true in generaL In the present case you wrote $ 1 = \frac{dy}{ds}, \ g(y)f(x) = \frac{dx}{ds}, \ 0 = z(x(s),y(s)) .$ This is equivalent to $ds=\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{dx}{- g(y)f(x)}=\frac{du}{0}$.

Third : Yes, $\Psi$ is the inverse of $\int 1/f$ .

Fourth : $c_1=\Phi(c_2)$ is a form of general solution $F(c_1,c_2)=0$ with arbitrary functions $F$ and $\Phi$ : (meaning arbitrary relationship).

Comment: Also see : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics . The symbol $t$ is used instead of $s$. And the symbol $z$ is used instead of $u$. In the present case $c(x,y,z)=0$.